# how can i get last record for chat conversion between two users?

Tags: mysql, laravel

=> I want to get the last record for chat conversion between two users based on created date field for getting the last message. below is my table

[image]

I have tried this query for getting the result of the last message of chat conversion but I can't get them right result.

```
select `chat_messages`.`id`, `chat_messages`.`message`, `chat_messages`.`created_at` 
from `chat_messages`
where `chat_messages`.`is_group` = 0 
and `chat_messages`.`deleted_at` is null 
and (`sender_id` =141 or `client_id` = 141)
group by `chat_messages`.`message_token` 
order by `chat_messages`.`created_at` desc
```

=> Current Result :-

[image]

=> Should be:-

[image]

**Note:-** This functionality is same like a chat functionality and i don't want to get only one record.

Thanks.

Comment: get data in desc order

Comment: @MaulikShah yes I have already tried short data in desc order.

Answer (score 1):

The `group by` was causing you the problem. All you need to do is sort desc and then limit the result set to one row

```
select `chat_messages`.`id`, `chat_messages`.`message`, `chat_messages`.`created_at` 
from `chat_messages`
where `chat_messages`.`is_group` = 0 
and `chat_messages`.`deleted_at` is null 
and (`sender_id` =141 or `client_id` = 141)
order by `chat_messages`.`created_at` desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: if use limit it will give only one right record but for this question, I want to get all last record for all conversation where sender_id is 141.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, Please check I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you grouping by `message_token`?

I think this query will be valid:

```sql
select `chat_messages`.`id`, `chat_messages`.`message`, `chat_messages`.`created_at` 
from `chat_messages`
where `chat_messages`.`message_token` = '144_141'
and `chat_messages`.`is_group` = 0 
and `chat_messages`.`deleted_at` is null 
order by `chat_messages`.`created_at` desc
limit 1
```

After your edit:

```sql
select `chat_messages`.`id`, `chat_messages`.`message`, `chat_messages`.`created_at`
from (select * from `chat_messages` order by `chat_messages`.`created_at` desc) as chat_messages
where `chat_messages`.`is_group` = 0
and `chat_messages`.`deleted_at` is null
and (`sender_id` =141 or `client_id` = 141)
group by `chat_messages`.`message_token`;
```

Comment: Please, check my new solution.

Comment: Thanks For your Efforts but it should not work for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you group by message_token you will join all those messages, you will have to select that message tread in an where statement where message_token = XXX.

```
SELECT 
    `chat_messages`.`id`, 
    `chat_messages`.`message`, 
    `chat_messages`.`created_at` 
FROM 
    `chat_messages`
WHERE 
    `chat_messages`.`is_group` = 0 
    and `chat_messages`.`deleted_at` is null 
    and (`sender_id` =141 or `client_id` = 141)
    and `chat_messages`.`message_token`= "146_141"
ORDER BY 
    `chat_messages`.`created_at` desc, 
    `chat_messages`.`id` desc
```

Comment: it will give only one record with id "7". please check my question and above database and what i should get record number "5" and "7" number id.

Comment: how about now ?

Comment: I get 2 records with the wrong message and the wrong id this is when I remove limit from your query. so please check my above database and updated question. what I should

Comment: question, how are we getting the wrong message and ID, when they are on the same row? we are not joining tables etc. I remove the limit I think it should work.. if not what result are you getting, can you post it?

Comment: Thanks For your Efforts but it should not work for me. +1

Comment: yes that's the idea, why it does not work, so I can help you if you still want help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188895/discussion-between-nimesh-patel-and-vidal).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have Message model (you're using laravel)

Below query should give you what do you want.

```
Message::whereSenderIdAndClientId($userId1,$userId2)
       ->orWhere([
             ["sender_id", $userId2],
             ["client_id",$userId1] 
         ])
       ->orderBy("created_at","desc")
       ->first()
```

Get messages between sender and client, order messages by created_at - desc then take first message which is last message between each other.